# Replace value with previous row if match the condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df=data.frame('Id'=c(101,101,102,102,103,103,104,104),'values'=c('a','b','a','c','a','d','a','c'))
```

I want to filter if there is any value b then it should be replaced by its previous row value.

I have tried this code but it's not working.

```
df%>%
  group_by(Id)%>%
  filter('b' %in% values)%>%
  mutate(values=lag(values))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this, but if first value is `'b'` then the first row will have NA for `lag`, you can adjust default value accordingly:

```
df%>%
   group_by(Id)%>%
     mutate(values = case_when(values == 'b' ~ lag(values, default = 'z'),
                             TRUE ~ values))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   Id [4]
     Id values
  <dbl> <chr> 
1   101 a     
2   101 a     
3   102 a     
4   102 c     
5   103 a     
6   103 d     
7   104 a     
8   104 c
```

Comment: First value is never going to be 'b', and this just output me the Id whose value is changed, I want change this in dataframe and others value should be same

Comment: @Nishant, You don't need `filter` option then, have changed the code, please check if that works.